# Importance of the $2^{\tau(G)}\leqslant A(n,g(G))$ conjecture

Tags: graph-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, coding-theory

During a course about finite dynamical systems the following conjecture was presented to us :

> Let G be a directed graph of order n.
>   Let $\tau(G)$ be the minimum size of a subset of $V(G)$, $I$ such that $G \setminus I$ is acyclic (Feedback Vertex Set).
>   Let $g(G)$ be the girth of $G$ (the minimum size of a cycle of $G$). If G is acyclic, let $g(G) = n+1$.
>   Let $A(n,d)$ be the maximum size of a subset $X \subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ such that the Hamming distance of two distinct elements of $X$ is always larger or equal than $d$.
>
> **Conjecture :** for all graphs $G$ of order $n$, $2^{\tau(G)}\leqslant A(n,g(G))$.

From my understanding, this is just an attempt to find properties of codes and of some particular graphs describing $A(n,d)$ (e.g. hypercubes of dimention $n$ for $A(n,1)$ or subgraphs of these hypercubes for $A(n,x)$). Is that true ?

Does $A(n,g(G))$ describe something useful in particular (in this case $G$ seems to describe the length of the words while it described the words themselves in the case of hypercubes) ?

Are there other consequences/implications ? Does the fact that G should be directed matter ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "subset $I$" of what? $V(G)$ or $E(G)$ "If $G$ is acyclic, let $g(G)=n+1$" where $n$ is what?

Comment: @bof: while you are right that this is not defined, it is clear from context that $I\subseteq V(G)$ and that $n=\lvert V(G)\rvert$. at potato: your mentioning 'codes' is indeed relevant, since e.g. according to [C. Godsil, *Algebraic Combinatorics*, CRC Press, 1993, ISBN 9780412041310; p. 205], the function $A(n,d)$ is the maximum cardinality of a *code* of *minimum distance* $d$ inside the $n$-dimensional hypercube.

Comment: @bof: It should be fixed now (I just transcribed one-to-one the paper we got).
PeterHeinig: thanks !

Comment: @PeterHeinig : does it make more sense now ?

Comment: @potato: it makes a little more sense; personally, I still don't understand what "graphs describing $A(n,d)$" is supposed to mean. Also, each of the three questions in the OP seems rather vague to me: 'is this an attempt?', 'are there consequences?', 'does G being directed matter?' I do not mean to be flippant, but strictly speaking the answer is three times 'obviously yes'. That being said, let me add that the most relevant publications I know (though still only trangentially so; in particular they are about *un*directed graphs) are: [D. A. Pike, *Decycling hypercubes*, ...

Comment: Graphs Comb. 19, No. 4, 547-550 (2003)], wherein a proof is given that if $Q_n$ is the $n$-dimensional hypercube, then $2^{n-1}-\tau(Q_n) = A(n,g(Q_n))$ if and only if $Q_n$ contains a minimum feedback set which moreover happens to be an *independent* set. I'm cognizant of this being merely roughly similar to the conjecture in the OP. Second, [Mieczysław Borowiecki, Ewa Drgas-Burchardt, *Acyclic homomorphisms to stars of graph Cartesian products and chordal bipartite graphs*, Discrete Math. 312, No. 14, 2146-2152 (2012)], in its last section has a few relevant remarks.

Answer (score 1):

Permit me to make a relevant (though inconclusive) observation regarding your question *"Does the fact that G should be directed matter?"*, an observation which lends some intuitive credibility to 'your' conjecture. I take that question to mean

> Is enough known about minimum feedback sets to *refute* the conjecture in the OP for **un**directed graphs?

In other words, can we disproof the conjecture

> **Conjecture 0.** For every *un*directed finite simple graph, $2^{\tau(G)}\leq A(n,g(G))$.

An obvious attempt to refute Conjecture 0 is to make use of a theorem of D. A. Pike in

> David A. Pike, *Decycling hypercubes.* Graphs Comb. 19, No.4, 547-550 (2003).

wherein a proof is given that

> **Theorem 1** If $n\in\omega$ is such that the $n$-dimensional hypercube $Q_n$ contains a minimum feedback vertex set which moreover is an *independent* set, then $\tau(Q_n) = 2^{n-1} - A(n,\tau(G_n))$.

If Conjecture 0 is true, then for any $n$ as in Theorem 1, and specializing to $G=Q_n$, it follows that (using that $g(Q_n)=4$),

> $2^{2^{n-1}}\quad\leq\quad A(n,4)\cdot 2^{A(n,4)}$ ${\hspace{163pt}}$ **(consequence)**

and deciding whether this is true or false is a matter of *pure coding theory*. It seems to me that this *is* true, so that 'your' conjecture *cannot be refuted* along the lines I am sketching: by the Gilbert-Varshamov bound we have

> $A(n,4) \geq \frac{2^n}{1 + n + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{3}}$

and this is comfortably large enough so that for all sufficiently large $n$, the *necessary* condition **(consequence)** *is* satisfied.